# sum of integers using order of integers and primitive roots

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Sorry for my interruption, I am looking for a solution to this question: Calculate
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2001}\left \lfloor \frac{2^k}{2003}\right \rfloor$$ without using computational engines, with $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denoting the largest integer that does not succeed x. I hope you can answer this question. And sorry for my mistakes, English is my second language.

Comment: Note:  I changed your notation for the floor function.  These days, I think it is more common to write $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for the floor, and $\lceil x \rceil$ for the ceiling (the least integer which is not less than $x$).  If you prefer the other notation, please change it back.

Comment: For what it's worth:  a (forbidden) computer calculation yields a formidable answer which this comment section is too small to allow me to reprint. This leads me to doubt that there is a terribly quick method, but who knows?

Comment: Dear lulu, thank you for correcting my mistakes. I am not familiar with LaTex codes, so I appreciated your help. Sincerely.

Comment: No problem, and I wouldn't really call it a mistake.  The notation you used was entirely standard not all that long ago, but I think the newer notation is better (as it lets us get at both floors and ceilings.

Comment: Entertainingly, the computed result is exactly the maximum number of characters the comments will allow...I can't even add the usual dollar signs to get the typeface right.  I'll post the computed solution in the next comment.  I think you'll agree that, at least in that form, it's hard to imagine an easy argument.  Of course it may be that this mess admits a nice interpretation, as a sum or difference of simply described exponents or such.

Comment: 229282215731254023810850364688503641342449865619310074983053966415529957342460372213012378695258366434038135724211175791002919413053031519006676256848058549254378410674612641039817831549156355210042789795433821756927839168539966777728041989097286777775147272208012778450213938303790936893731730847669161620257950891631469806495016444948405509537563208188575142719334250285615592875159822849248662772475699648518015812535240698668804877004200066403476564021771526551282991080558506318841901062839002661518483126477735427914825334836609195224993061974803045782197760960205377475422796712455686173037500

Comment: @Mathwriter:  if you have an explicit expression you should add it as an answer.  The FAQ encourages that.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sorry for my last comment. In fact my answer was wrong, and I am still looking for an explicit expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we write $2^k=2003q_k+r_k$ you are looking for the sum of the $q_k$.  Assume for the moment that we know that $2$ is a primitive root $\bmod 2003$.  In that case the $r_k$ run through all the numbers from $1$ through $2002$ and we can write 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2001}\Big \lfloor \frac{2^k}{2003}\Big \rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{2001} \frac {2^k-r_k}{2003}=\frac {2^{2002}-1}{2003}-\frac {2002\cdot 2003}{2\cdot 2003}=\frac {2^{2002}-1}{2003}-1001$$
This gives an explicit expression without summation or floor functions, but actually computing it is beyond most of our patience as it will have about $600$ digits.

I don't have an easy way to show $2$ is a primitive root.  The order of $2$ must divide $2002=2\cdot7\cdot 11 \cdot 13$ so we can just check whether $2$ to any of $14$ powers is equivalent to $1 \bmod 2003$.  You can generate $2^{2^n}$ by repeated squaring and then multiply them, but it will be tedious.

I realized that all that is needed for this argument to work is to show $2^{1001}\equiv -1 \pmod {2003}$, which will be true if $2$ is a primitive root but might be otherwise.  With repeated squaring that is more within the range of hand computation, but still tedious.

Comment: Dear Ross Millikan. Thank you for your answer! However 2 is not a primitive root of 2003. In fact order of 2 mod 2003 is actualy 286?. But I understand your idea and I appreciated your help. Sincerely.

Comment: @Mathwriter:  when I see a  problem like this I try to find ways to bring the calculation into a range of what is reasonable.  Probably knowing that $2$ is not a primitive root $\bmod 7$ should have tipped me off.  The fact that it is not primitive may change the $1001$ that is subtracted a bit.

Comment: @Mathwriter:  the fact that $2$ is not a primitive root can change the $1001$ term in my expression, but not by much.  Most of the digits of the answer will be correct.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give the explicit expression?

Comment: It is just six times the sum of all the powers of $2$ $\pmod {2003}$divided by $2003$.  Six comes from $2003/286=6$ so you go around six times.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan: Can you give the sum of all  of all the powers of $2 (mod 2003)$? And generally, is there a way to find the sum of all the powers of $a$ $(mod p)$ with every integer $a$ and prime $p$ that is co prime with $a$?

Comment: I don’t know of one. It is easy to do in a spreadsheet for a specific case. That is why I was hoping that $2$ was a primitive root, so all the remainders are there

Comment: For comparison, if we replace $2003$ with $7$, the powers of $2 \pmod 7$ are $1,2,4$, so the sum of the remainders is $1+2+4+1+2+4=14$ instead of $21$, so the subtraction would be $2$, not $3$

Comment: Hint: since $2^{1001}$ $=-1$ $mod  2003 $ then $ 2^{1001 + i} + 2^i = 0 (mod 2003)$, thus $ \left \lfloor{\frac{2^{1001 + i}}{2003}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{2^{i}}{2003}}\right \rfloor  = \frac{2^{1001 + i} + 2^i}{2003} - 1$

Answer (score 0):

Solution from a friend of mine: Since $$2^{1001}=-1(mod  2003) $$ then $$ 2^{1001 + i} + 2^i = 0 (mod 2003),$$ thus $$ \left \lfloor{\frac{2^{1001 + i}}{2003}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{2^{i}}{2003}}\right \rfloor  = \frac{2^{1001 + i} + 2^i}{2003} - 1,$$ therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^{2001}\Big \lfloor \frac{2^k}{2003}\Big \rfloor=\frac {2^{2002}-1}{2003}-1001$$

Comment: I had said that $2^{1001}\equiv -1 \bmod 2003$ was enough to show the subtraction was $1001$.  I just realized that if you know the order of $2$ is $286$ the fact that $2002/286=7$ it is enough to show this.  I don't know how to prove that without direct computation.